# How to implement snap points with an inertia-enabled control

Tags: c, user-interface, winapi, touch

I am currently in the process of implementing a custom slider control. The control can be operated with both a pointing device as well as a touch input device.

To provide a consistent and familiar user experience the control uses a simple physics model provided by the [Inertia API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd371570.aspx) included in Windows 7. I have set up both an [`IManipulationProcessor`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd372579.aspx) and an [`IInertiaProcessor`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd372061.aspx) that are hooked up to my [`_IManipulationEvents`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd317344.aspx) implementation. The event routing is in place and upon completion of the manipulation processing the inertia processor is invoked, performing the trajectory calculations.

So far, so good. However, I cannot get my head around how to incorporate snap points into this setup. By snap points I am referring to the behavior, that the slider should only be allowed to land at predefined points, and not in between. Neither the `IManipulationProcessor` nor the `IInertiaProcessor` seem to have direct support for this. Tacking this behavior onto the end of inertia processing is possible, but will fail to supply movement information for the typical visual feedback.

So where and how do you implement snap points?

Answer (score 0):

You need to assign an upper and lower threshold to the snap points and if the trajectory will land within a snap point range then replace the projected stopping point with the snap point location...beware of patent application 12/983106
which was published as U.S. Publication 2012/0174005.  You might find yourself with patent infringement issues.

Comment: Unfortunately there is no (direct) way to query the `IInertiaProcessor` for the predicted landing point. While it may be possible to set the elastic margins and boundaries, there's no way to know ahead of time where to put them. Thanks for pointing out the patent, though, although I believe I will be safe.